# Two HttpPost filters in one controller. One for Html.BeginForm other for ajax.BeginForm both called on form submit

Tags: ajax, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I am trying to add enhancement to an asp.net mvc4 application. I abstracted my changes by adding them to a partial view, and I wanted to make use of ajax to display changes to the user without a page refresh. There was already a form on the page created by using the html helper method.

So in the controller the methods are:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult AMN()
    {
        string remarks = " ";
        return PartialView(((object)remarks));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AMN(string PN= null)
    {
      ...return Json(remarks);

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PS()
    {
        ...return View(pS);

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PS(PSModel pS)
    {    
        ...return View(pS);
```

My Ajax calls and JSON works fine, the page loads correctly, but when the submit button is used for the html.beginform, and the page refreshes it calls both post methods.. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I fixed it by changing the names of the get method for the partialview and post method for the form on the partial.

```
       // [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult AMN()
    {
        string remarks = " ";
        return PartialView(((object)remarks));
    }

   // [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult JSONMN(string PN = null)
```